# How can I get the updated value only from a useeffect without it first returning the initial value null?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

I am creating an auth hook that checks whether user is authenticated from the server and returns the value.

```
export function useAuth() {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        let mounted = true;
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/still-authenticated/',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            withCredentials: true,
        })
        .then((res) => {
            if (mounted) {
                setIsAuthenticated(res.data.isAuthenticated);
            }
        });

        return () => mounted = false;
    },[setIsAuthenticated])

    return isAuthenticated;
}
```

While testing the function I noticed that it first returns null and then updates the value with the axios fetch which is either true/false.

Now my question: Is there a way for me to only receive the updated value in react without the use of useeffect (I tried useLayoutEffect and it doesn't work either)?

Comment: I think you are looking for Suspense. Or a simple loader `if (isAuthenticated === null) return <Loader />`. Your app has to be doing SOMETHING while its fetching the data.

Comment: shouldn't that be isAuthenticated rather than setIsAuthenticated in the square bracket.

Comment: Ok cool, I think the behaviour I want is for it to get the result before a render. But I'll try that, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the comments want you to do something like the following. I agree, use a loader while you are fetching data from the API.

```
export function useAuth() {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        let mounted = true;
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/still-authenticated/',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            withCredentials: true,
        })
        .then((res) => {
            if (mounted) {
                setIsAuthenticated(res.data.isAuthenticated);
            }
        });

        return () => mounted = false;
    },[isAuthenticated])

    return {isAuthenticated ? isAuthenticated : {/*INSERT LOADER HERE OR TEXT*/}};
}
```